# What causes a #1066 - Not unique table/alias and how should it be fixed?

Tags: mysql

This is the SQL query:

```
SELECT
    `cards.ID` AS ID,
    `cards.SetName` AS SetName,
    `variations.varCARDID` AS varCARDID,
    `variations.varID` AS varID,
    `collections.have` AS have,
    `variations.varTTP` AS varTTP,
    `variations.varPOP` AS varPOP,
    `collections.userID` AS userID,
    `collections.relID` AS relID
FROM
    `cards` AS C,
    `variations` AS V,
    `collections` AS Co
JOIN
    C
ON
    `cards.ID` = `variations.varCARDID`
JOIN
    V
ON
    `variations.varID` = `collections.relID`
WHERE
    `cards.SetName` = 'Ancient Origins' AND `collections.userID` = 2
```

Here is the table structures

table cards:

- ID
- setName

table variations:

- varCARDID
- varID
- varTTP
- varPOP

table collections:

- have
- userID
- relID

What I am trying to achieve:

A list of cards(and its variations) owned by a specific user for a particular set.

I have altered my origination code bases on about 6 articles from here(stackoverflow) and am getting the same results.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

Here is the original code I started with before I tried to fix it:

```
SELECT
    cards.ID AS ID,
    cards.SetName AS SetName,
    variations.varCARDID AS varCARDID,
    variations.varID AS varID,
    collections.have AS have,
    variations.varTTP AS varTTP,
    variations.varPOP AS varPOP,
    collections.userID AS userID,
    collections.relID AS relID
FROM
    cards,
    variations,
    collections
JOIN
    cards
ON
    cards.ID = variations.varCARDID
JOIN
    variations
ON
    variations.varID = collections.relID
WHERE
    cards.SetName = 'Ancient Origins' AND collections.userID = 2
```

Comment: Don't mix old join syntax (comma separated) with new JOIN syntax. if you do you get a kinds off wierd errors.... `FROM
    `cards` AS C,` and `JOIN
    C` is the same alias that's why you get your error.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I am not sure how to fix it based on what you said; Link to proper documentation or edit what I have?

Comment: You have aliased variations as V and then you attempt to join V. Not sure if join is to variations?

Comment: @P.Salmon That was one of the suggestions in another article I will edit to show what I started with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I went with this as a solution:

```
$sql_new="SELECT `cards`.`ID`, `collections`.`relID`, `variations`.`varCARDID`, `variations`.`varID`, `variations`.`varName`, `variations`.`varTTP` AS TTP, `variations`.`varPOP` AS POP, `collections`.`have` AS have, `collections`.`userID` From `cards`, `variations`, `collections` WHERE `cards`.`SetName` = '" .$row["SetName"] . "' AND `variations`.`varCARDID` = `cards`.`ID` AND `collections`.`relID` = `variations`.`varCARDID` AND `collections`.`have`>0 AND `collections`.`userID` = " . $_SESSION["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Select ...
From cards c
Join variations v on v.Varcardid = c.id
Join collections co on co.id = v.varid
Where ...

Comment: That gives me this #1054 - Unknown column 'cards.ID' in 'field list'?